# SimpleXMLElement single quote encode

Tags: php

I use SimpleXMLElement to generate XML and one of the child notes got a sentense in it that got a single quote, the receiver then fail... How can I encode the sentense to change the single quote.

Code:

```
$objLeadXML = new SimpleXMLElement ( '<CancelLead/>' );

    $cancelReason = $objLead->getReasonForCancelling ();
    $cancelReason = str_replace("\'", "&#39;", $cancelReason);

    $objLeadElement = $objLeadXML->addChild ( 'Lead', $cancelReason );
    $objLeadElement->addAttribute ( 'ELMSRef', $objLead->getID () );
    $objLeadElement->addAttribute ( 'CancelDate', $objLeadHistory->ActionDate );
    $objLeadElement->addAttribute ( 'IsCancelled', $objLead->getStatusID () == KStatus::CANCELLED ? 1 : 0 );
    $objLeadElement->addAttribute ( 'CancelledBy', $objLeadHistory->PerformedBy );
```

The $cancelReason contain a cancellation reason like "No Driver's License" I need to encode the single quote in that sentence.

Comment: Please provide some code to help explain what it is you're doing/trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace("\'", "&#39", $parentString);`

Or ´ instead of \' , if it is the acute symbol.

Comment: You don't need to escape the single-quote inside of double-quotes.

Comment: Also, it should be `&#39;` (note the semicolon).